# Will Conceal Spell or Cunning Caster let me use Oracle’s Burden undetected?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, spellcasting

I want to use [Oracle’s Burden](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/oracle-s-burden/) on unsuspecting Non Player Characters, for roleplay purposes. Knowing this is a Curse I want to use the spell with one of the two feats:

- [Conceal Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/conceal-spell/)
- [Cunning Caster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/cunning-caster/)

Will this be enough to completely conceal my actions even against spellcasters with high spellcraft skill?

Will they react in any way?

P.S.
My Oracle [Curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses/)
 is Aboleth, so no visual effect on the victim.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143484/8610) about this these feats. Further, you may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44775/8610) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63677/8610) about the effects of spells on unsuspecting or unaware creatures.

Comment: All this to add -2 to their saves against mind effects?

Comment: @ShadowKras The GM sed that being a Oracle and having a curse that is not such a big deal, is not fun. So with me decided to awaken a link with me and a 24CR Aboleth, when I interact just once on every character using diplomacy intimidation or bluff. So when i Share my burden i can make a character be taken over by the aboleth.

Comment: So, why do you need two different effects, that do mostly the same, to work together?

Comment: @ShadowKras chaos, fear factor, disposing an undesired persona from a civilized position…

Comment: Guys, you are allowed to *just answer the question*. Clarification can be great, but there’s nothing here that is unclear—why Andrew wants to do this is really his own business and it doesn’t matter for the sake of the question, which is really entirely straightforward. Close votes and badgering comments are really not appropriate here. This is someone who just wants to know if a rules interaction works the way he thinks it does, we can answer that without needing to know why he’s interested in the interaction.

Comment: @KRyan without clarification, answers will simply repeat the content of those two feats and comment on it. So it's basically a "yes/no" question that could be answered by reading the two feats.

Comment: @ShadowKras OK, great, then *you can answer the question,* why didn’t you just do that? If the querent wants more information after they learn the answer to the question they asked, they can very easily ask a new question. Clarifications are important, but second-guessing people’s questions isn’t—really, to be honest with you, I find it really rude and it’s been something that has certainly bothered me on my own few questions.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, they will

Though people can still notice if they pass their checks.

For [Cunning Caster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/cunning-caster/), you must make a [Bluff](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/bluff) check with a -4 penalty (for the verbal component), opposed by a [Perception](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception) check of all who see you. If they fail the check, the spell effect still goes off, but they can't tell it was *you* casting the spell. If they pass, they will notice that you were responsible for the spell.

For [Conceal Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/conceal-spell/), you attempt to **conceal the manifestation of casting the spell**, which means there will be no visual magical effects going on should you succeed. For that, you take a *full-round action* to cast the spell instead of the normal *standard action*, but you make no check. Other creatures must make a Perception, Sense Motive or Spellcraft check (whichever is better for them) against DC 15 + your ranks in Bluff or Disguise (whichever is higher) + your Charisma Mod. They gain a bonus on this check equal to the spell level (+2).

If they fail, the only thing they will notice is that you raised your voice to say something, but nothing that makes it obvious that *you* cast a spell will be noticeable. As the spell has nothing obvious on targets, there isn't much they can do to notice the target was affected by a spell. They still can use *Detect Magic* and *Spellcraft* or *Knowledge (Arcana)* to notice the spell effects, but there won't be anything linking it to your character.

### But I would advise against using both

If you want to use both feats, you are effectively using two different feats that will accomplish pretty much the same thing (hide the fact that you just cast a spell). As such, I can see why some GMs might ask you to pick one or the other when casting a spell. I would advise you take only one of those, preferably *Conceal Spell*, and take [Silent Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/silent-spell-metamagic/) instead of *Cunning Caster*. This way, you can completely conceal the spell manifestation and there won't be any words coming out of your mouth to even suggest you tried something sketchy.

*Cunning Caster* does nothing to hide the *spell's manifestation*, which is a real thing even for spells with no components at all, it simply won't be obvious that you were manifesting the spell. Everybody will still notice that a spell was cast, which is concealed by *Conceal Spell*.

Comment: The question as currently posed asks after “one of these two feats,” and the original formulation was “either” of them. I don’t get any impression that the querent was going to try to use both at the same time. Still might be worth addressing, but your current phrasing doesn’t quite match what the question’s actually asking.

Comment: Sorry guy's I didnt respond sooner, was trying to gather more information on the subject before sharing with everyone what information i have gathered from the paizo site, official PDF's and forum discussions and sites provided by @"Hey I Can Chan"
To sum it all up:

Comment: When you cast you manifest visible magic(so warriors life would be easy).
Spellcraft usefull only when you spend time using detect magic, or see the spell being cast.
Knowledge arcana only if you know you are affected by a spell.
What i dont know and is only to be anwsered by a creator, or my GM, will any target feel a change when affected by a spell he didnt saw comming be warrior or wizard. Anyway I thank everyone involved in advance.

Comment: @Andrewtheoracle you can identify spells are they are being cast using Spellcraft. Arcana is only to identify effects already in place. And yes, you feel when you have been affected by any spell, unless the spell says otherwise. See [Subtle Enchantments](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/subtle-enchantments/)

Comment: @ShadowKras So far as I can tell that feat doesn't describe what a creature feels when it *is* affected by a spell; it only describes what happens when a creature is *not* affected. That is, when the feat says, "If the foe fails the saving throw or is otherwise affected by the spell, the Sense Motive DC to notice she is under the effects of an enchantment increases by 5," it's talking about outside observers discerning the mental control effect.